# Monitor data (internet) usage

Tags: iphone, monitor

Is there a  way to monitor how much data(internet) each application used?

If I cannot monitor applications is there a way to get all internet requests information?
(get data passed, url, etc)

(I would like to use this info in an app Im developing for iphone)

Answer (score 2):

No, you only have access to your own application's sandbox, and therefore can only track the network usage of your own application.

Comment: Thanks
is there some kind of system object that can throw an event every time a connection is open?
or some other workaround?

Comment: The Reachability sample project will throw a notification when network reachability options change, but that wouldn't help you with tracking usage. You could jailbreak the phone. That's the only workaround I know.

Comment: No you can check [this](http://itunes.apple.com/in/app/data-usage/id386950560?mt=8) application on iTunes [this](http://itunes.apple.com/in/app/data-usage/id386950560?mt=8) application is doing what is asked in the question